# Data table is changing DateTime format upon bind. Asp.net

Tags: datetime, datatable

Put simply, I am binding a data table to a database table. 
In the database table, the format is:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff
```

But the data table stores these as:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

The table is filled using an SQL Data Adapter.

Any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: The data in the database table is (hopefully) being stored in a `datetime` column. In which case, it doesn't *have* a format. The format's you're showing are (presumably) the default way that two different components are choosing to format the `datetime` value for display purposes. Whether either of these can be changed (and which one you want to change) probably depends on the specific components.

Comment: I'd want to keep the database format in this case. I'm going to see if I could maybe bind the data table column by column rather than at one go, and do a programmatic conversion during this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can only format the displayed value of a `DateTime` object, not the object itself. Therefore if you use e.g. a `DataGridView` to display the query result, you can define a custom cell style format

```
 var dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
 dataGridViewCellStyle1.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
 dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that you are using asp.net